# AngularJS renders a element instead of the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a problem with my AngularJS view. I use the flex-slider directive to render, who expected, a carousel slider. There are also a other directives I created myself for list items, loading overlay and for a sticky box.

The problem is when I reload the page and everything is loaded and shout get rendered my flex-slider just wrap the html in to an "a" element instead of the flexslider html given from it's template. If I remove one of the other directive it's rendered correctly.

Is there a limit of how much directives are allowed to be inside one view? 
Or is it maybe a problem with the flexslider directive? Or have the Illuminati to do something with it?

Thanks for any use- and/or helpful answer!

**Edit**

```
.directive('sticky', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            function sticky_relocate() {
                var window_top = window.scrollY;
                var div_top = document.getElementById("sticky-anchor").offsetTop;
                if (window_top > div_top) {
                    angular.element(elem).addClass('stick');
                } else {
                    angular.element(elem).removeClass('stick');
                }
            }

            angular.element(window).bind("scroll", function() {
                sticky_relocate();
            });
            sticky_relocate();
        }
    };
}]);
```

[Link to the flex-slider directive](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider)

**Edit 2**

Strange thing is, when I delete the html inside my sticky directive the flex-slider starts to work again.

HTML inside the directive:

```
<div sticky id="sticky" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-10">
    <img ng-src="{{ ::company.logo }}" class="img-responsive"/>
    <strong>{{ ::company.name }}</strong><br><br>
    <a ng-href="/firma/{{ ::company.company_link.companyIdent }}/{{ ::company.company_link.companyHash }}/{{ ::company.company_link.companyId }}">Zum Newsroom &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><a/>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh snap, there was just the closing a tag wrong ... <a/> instead of </a>...